# css not showing up in rails app view if content is nil

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

In my new.html.erb, I have this on top:

```
<div id="errors">
  <%= flash[:error] %>
</div>
```

So, I learned that the div id "errors" doesn't show up if flash[:error] is nil i.e. flash[:error] returns nil and is never set. Why is this and is that true? Is there documentation on this? Why doesn't the div id tag show up on the page when flash[:error] returns nil?

IS there an implied conditional around the div tags that checks whether flash[:error] is truthy?

Comment: If my memory is good enough, #errors will show up whatever flash[:error] is. But I’m not sure I get your question here…

Answer (score 0):

> IS there an implied conditional around the div tags that checks whether flash[:error] is truthy?

No - there is no implicit conditional.

The element is being rendered - check your page's source - but you aren't seeing it because its text node is empty.

[From the docs:](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Flash.html)

```
#show.html.erb

<% if flash[:notice] %>
  <div class="notice"><%= flash[:notice] %></div>
<% end %>
```